# difference between send() and sendTo() in C for a UDP network implementation

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to implement a UDP network between a client and a server but in many implementations, they use either `send()` or `sendTo()` I tried looking in the man pages but I didn't really understand the difference other than that the `sendTo()` takes in more arguments which makes it look rather useless compared to `send()`. If you could bring any clarity on this matter I would be happy to hear :)

Comment: From The Fine Manual: `The  send()  call may be used only when the socket is in a connected state (so that the intended recipient is known).`

Comment: Chances are you want `sendto` . The "extra arguments" are what make it work for UDP connectionless datagrams. You still use a socket, but sendto does the binding to the specified target, does the message drop, then unbinds, etc. for you. in short, there is no `connect` client-side.

Comment: `sendTo()` doesn't exist. You mean `sendto()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sendto` function is the one that's generally used for UDP sockets.  As UDP is connectionless, this function allows you to specify the IP and port that each outgoing packet is sent to.

You can however also use `send` if you first use `connect`.  The `connect` function can be used to specify the destination IP and port for all packets sent using `send`.  It also restricts the packets you receive to just those from that IP/port.  The `connect` function may be called multiple times to change the associated remote IP/port, or to remove the association.

In general, I would recommend sticking with `sendto` as it gives you more flexibility over who you're sending to.